# How to use Blazor bind:set and bind:get correctly?

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to use the new blazor value-binding with separete get and set.
Somehow my code does not work and I get this compiler-exception:

Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<string>' to 'System.Action<string?>'

My code:

```
<input type="text"
    @bind:get="text"
    @bind:set="SetValue" />
    
@code {
    private string text = string.Empty;

    private void SetValue(string value)
    {
        text = value;
    }
}
```

I tried to use this.text in the @bind:get and i tried to use @bind-value but it did not change anything

Meanwhile, this code works totally fine:

```
<input type="text"
    @bind="Text" />

@code {
    private string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set => SetValue(value);
    }

    private string text;

    private void SetValue(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Update: The second code snipped does not work anymore (it does not show the value correct in the input field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the latest updates to Visual Studio and Net7.0.  `@bind:after` is another story!

Pre March 2023 releases had the issue you have highlighted, but it was fixed in the latest 17.5 release.  See the screen shots below.

No Errors showing:

[image: strong text]

Running:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have used the latest preview version. With the normal version it has now also worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is a know [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44957). I was able to make `bind:get`/`bind:set` work by installing .NET 8 Preview 2 as suggested in this [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44957#issuecomment-1476977576).

Comment: You just need the latest VS Studio, SDK and Net 7 to fix the OP's issue.  @bind:after is another issue and still a mess as highlighted in the reference you've provided.  The Razor Compiler just isn't handling it properly.